# How do I activate an order in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, order

When I try to activate an order in Lightning I get the error "Can't activate the order. Make sure the status field has an Activated picklist value and try again":

[image]

There are two statuses identified as "Activated" and when I switch back to Classic (without changing anything) it works perfectly.  Is there an additional setting somewhere or trick to activating orders in Lightning?

Comment: In lightning are you using quick action to activate it?

Comment: I'm using the standard Activate button that appears on the form.  Deactivate works correctly, but Activate fails with the error above.  When I switch back to Classic, the button works fine.  Lightning is apparently missing something that allows it to pick up the proper "Activated" status, but for the life of me I can't figure out why that is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue right now, however, one thing you can check; the activate status is driven off of the native Status field.  It's one of those "special" native picklists that allows you to define a label and API name as well as a purpose.  In this case, it's status of the order, which you have two options: Draft or Activated. Ensure you have at least one Status pickval set to Activated.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I double-checked and I am using the default Order Status field and have two picklist values associated with the Status Category of "Activated".  Again, I know it's right because all I have to do is switch back to Classic and it works perfectly.  Something in Lightning is tripping it up.

Comment: I had a thought that maybe having two "Activated" statuses could be the problem so I removed one, but the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning is apparently looking for a status of "Activated", ***not*** a status category of "Activated".  Once I added a new status that literally said "Activated", the Activate button worked perfectly.